# What does the pipe symbol mean in an equation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, computer-science

Currently reading through an algorithm and in the algorithm there is an array of random numbers ($r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$, and $r_4$).

The criteria for each number in the array is {$r_n ∈ R \mid 0 ≤ r_n ≤ 1$}. Which I presume means each value of the array needs to be a real number but I can't work out what the pipe symbol means, does it mean an **OR** or does it mean it must be a number **AND** between 0 & 1?

Comment: pipe symbol? You mean $\in$? Anyway the way to read $\{r_n\in R\,|\, 0\leq r_n\leq 1\}$ is "the set of all $r_n$ belonging to the set $R$ such that $0\leq r_n\leq 1$". (btw if you wish to refer to the real numbers, the standard symbol is $\Bbb{R}$.)

Comment: That's set builder notation. It means "such that."

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Make perfect sense. I always see `|` as an OR symbol.

Comment: Just to clarify does that mean $0 ≤ r_n ≤ 1$ doesn't mean between 0 & 1? I thought it was meant the value of $r_n$ had to be a float value

Comment: No, $0\leq r_n\leq 1$ *does* mean that it's between 0 and 1. peek-a-boo's description is correct.

Comment: In math the symbol for OR is $\lor$... LaTex \lor.... AND is $\land$... Latex \land.... & you can write $\lor_{i=1}^5P_i$ for $P_1\lor P_2\lor P_3\lor P_4\lor P_5$. (Similarly with  $\land_{i=1}^5P_i\;$.)

Comment: See [the third symbol here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols#Miscellaneous) for a list of typical conventions of `|`.

Comment: Sometimes the colon $\; :\;$ is used instead of "pipe".

Comment: Do not call it "pipe" when talking to mathematicians.  Is the term "pipe" even used except in a few programming settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is a cultural divide. It is common in computer science for the pipe, that is, the symbol $|$, to mean "or" (the [logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)).

In mathematics, the notation $\{A | B\}$, sometimes written $\{A:B\}$, means "the set of all $A$ such that $B$." The logical disjunction is often just written as "or", although $\vee$ is also common in more formal settings.